# Orthogonal vectors $a, b$, with $b$ lying in a subspace $S$, will $a$ be orthogonal to all the subspace $S$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, orthogonality

If we've two orthogonal vectors $a, b$, with $b$ lying in a subspace $S$, will $a$ be orthogonal to all the subspace $S$?

If the subspace is a line or a plane ,I can see its true. Can we prove it for higher dimensions as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true even if $S$ is a plane. Take $S=\{(x,y,0)\mid x,y\in\Bbb R\}$ in $\Bbb R^3$, $a=(1,0,1)$, and $b=(0,1,0)(\in S)$. Then $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal, but $a$ is *not* orthogonal to the whole plane $S$.

Comment: thank you, but I meant one of the vector shouldn't be in the subspace as I've mentioned above.

Comment: I've edited my answer.